# Series with more terms converges more slowly than with lesser terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I was working with the Laplace differential equation with certain boundary conditions, problem that yields the following analytic solution:

$$
\mathbb{V}(x,y)= \mathbb{V}_o\frac{4}{\pi}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{2n+1}\sin\biggl(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{L}\biggl)\exp{(-y(2n+1)\pi/L)}
$$

When plotting this as a function of $y$ leaving $x$ fixed, I have noticed that, contrary to what I expected, it's not true that for more terms in the sum the function converges more quickly. In the image below appears the behavior I'm describing:

[image]

I don't know if this question is too elementary, but I'm quite curious as to why this happens. Is it because of some property of the series, or is it just a numerical issue?

Edit: this only happens in the first few terms. From around $n=10$ and so on it behaves "correctly", in the sense that for more terms it converges more quickly.